# Recall the char function

Tags: c, cs50

I'm very new to programming, and I'm doing a simple bot in C, that has a calculator function. I'm having some trouble in this piece of code:

```
char operation = get_char("Insert the mathematical operation: ");
float x = get_float("X: ");
float y = get_float("Y: ");
if (operation == 43)
{
    float result = (x + y);
    int rresult = round(result);
    printf("X + Y = %i\n", rresult);
    string confirmation = get_string("Need to do something more? ");
    if (strcmp(confirmation, "Y") == 0)
    {
        return operation;
    }
```

As you can see, this calculator ask the user for a char (*, /, + or - [its everything defined in the other parts of the code, I will not post it here just to be brief] that defines the math operation and then, after doing the calculation and printing the result, asks the user if he wants to do more calculations. If the answer is "Y" (yes), I want to restart this piece of code, asking for the char and the floats, and doing everything. I want to know the simplest way to do this, without making the code looks bad designed.
Also, I'm using CS50 IDE.

Comment: `operation == 43` should be `operation == '+'`

Comment: You need to move the bit of code that does the calculation into a separate function, and then you can call that function in a loop

Comment: It seems like a bad design to have the prompt to continue inside the `if(operation == '+')` loop.  I would expect you to do that prompt for every operation.  You want to minimize the differences between the cases.

Comment: You might want a [variable reduction operator](https://cdecl.org/?q=declare+reduction+as+array+256+of+pointer+to+function+%28float%2C+float%29+returning+float) to replace your `if` -> `if(reduce[operation]) answer = reduce[operation](x, y)`.

Comment: Ok ok, thanks everyone who commented here. I used 43 (and other numbers for other operations) because its the ASCII code for the +, but I will replace with the + or - or * or /. About the prompting, I realized this some time after posting here and changed it sucessfully.  Also, I will read about this variable reduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have CS50, therefore, plain C. The construct you might want to use is a do-while loop.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

char get_char(char * msg) {char c; printf("%s", msg); scanf(" %c", &c); return c;}
float get_float(char * msg) {float f; printf("%s", msg); scanf(" %f", &f); return f;}

int main() {
    char confirmation = 'n';
    do {
        char operation = get_char("Insert the mathematical operation: ");
        float x = get_float("X: ");
        float y = get_float("Y: ");
        if (operation == '+') {
            float result = (x + y);
            printf("Result in float: %f\n", result);
            int rresult = round(result);
            printf("X + Y = %i\n", rresult);
        }
        confirmation = get_char("Need to do something more [y/n]? ");
    } while (confirmation == 'y');
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall dowhile.c
$ ./a.out            
Insert the mathematical operation: +
X: 0.11
Y: 0.88
Result in float: 0.990000
X + Y = 1
Need to do something more [y/n]? y
Insert the mathematical operation: +
X: 0.1
Y: 0.1
Result in float: 0.200000
X + Y = 0
Need to do something more [y/n]? n
$
```